# Having trouble using sed command in MAC

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to do the following:

```
LC_CTYPE=C sed 's/|/¦/g' t.txt > new_t.txt
```

The code is working but, when I open the new file, the replace adds an additional character "A¦". Why is that?

Comment: Depends on how you typed the ¦ character and how you are viewing the file. I'm guessing your command line represented that as UTF-8 whereas you are apparently using something else (Latin-1?) to view the file (though strictly speaking that should give you `Â¦`, not `A¦`). Perhaps see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: As regards your question before me editing it, [**do not use signature, taglines, or greetings**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate, but I fail to find one which is very specific to `sed` on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

When you typed

```sh
LC_CTYPE=C sed 's/|/¦/g' t.txt > new_t.txt
```

your shell was *probably* configured to accept the *command itself*  as UTF-8, and so in fact you ended up converting the single byte 0x7C ([U+007C](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007c/index.htm)) to the two bytes 0xC2 0xA6 which is the correct UTF-8 encoding for [U+00A6](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a6/index.htm).

What you *then* did is unclear, but somehow you ended up examining the file in some other encoding than UTF-8, which exposes the two bytes as the string you report seeing.

The correct workaround is to examine the file in a correctly configured program which supports UTF-8.